# Convert list of longs to list of doubles

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am new to Streams, I have a list of long values. And I want to convert the list of long values to list of double values using stream.

Here is the code:

```
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(4L);
list.add(92L);
list.add(100L);
```

I want to convert the list to a `List<double>`. Thanks

Comment: Stream the list, map the values to double and collect them in a list...

Comment: `List<Double> collect1 = list.stream().mapToDouble(s -> s).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Nit: You can't get a `List<double>`! It would either be `List<Double>` or `double[]` that you can get.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use the `map` operator to convert `Long` into a `Double` and then use the `toList` collector.

```
List<Double> doubleValues = list.stream()
    .map(Double::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Conversely, if you are concerned about the overhead of autoboxing, you can create an array of `double`. Here's how it looks.

```
double[] doubleArr = list.stream().mapToDouble(v -> v).toArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Double> collect1 = list.stream()
          .mapToDouble(s -> s) // DoubleStream
          .boxed()  // Stream<Double>
          .collect(Collectors.toList());  //collected to List<Double>
```

caution: `boxing()` is overhead.

---

Another way around, without `boxing()`

```
List<Double> listDouble = new ArrayList<>();
list.stream().mapToDouble(s->s).forEach(k->listDouble.add(k));
```

Comment: @Holger `.map(s->s)` will give `Stream<Long>` which I don't want , though I could have done `map(e -> Double.valueOf(e))` to get `Stream<Double>` and then collect it,but it was already posted in answer by others, so I went to use `.mapToDouble(s -> s).boxed()` to provide a flavor of alternative solution. I have also do added a solution without `.boxing()`

Comment: Ok, because `.mapToDouble(s -> s)` is doing `(double)s.longValue()` implicitly. You could do `.map(Long::doubleValue)` instead. But I’m not recommending to avoid `.boxed()` at all costs, the boxing still happens in every variant and doing it in `forEach` is the worst of them. You can collect a `DoubleStream` directly to a `List` via `List<Double> collect2 = list.stream().mapToDouble(s -> s) .collect(ArrayList::new, List::add, List::addAll);`, but still, the boxing is there, unavoidably, as the result `List<Double>` *is* a list of boxed doubles.

Comment: @Holger , i understand what you are saying. The boxing is unavoidable in this case, either it will happen implicitly or explicitly. I just gave my answer in thought to provide a different flavor for viewers.

Answer (score 3):

Try something in the line of:

```
List<Double> doubles = list.stream()
         .map(e -> Double.valueOf(e))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Explanation

```
list.stream().
```

This makes you create (and iterate over) a stream.

```
map(e -> Double.valueOf(e))
```

each (Long) element you iterate over, will be mapped to a Double

```
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This maps it to a `List<Double>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without boxing `long` and `double` values using [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections):

```
LongList longs = LongLists.mutable.with(4L, 92L, 100L);
DoubleList doubles = longs.collectDouble(l -> l, DoubleLists.mutable.empty());

Assert.assertEquals(DoubleLists.mutable.with(4.0, 92.0, 100.0), doubles);
```

You can also do this with Java Streams and Eclipse Collections converting from a `List<Long>` to a `DoubleList`:

```
List<Long> list = Arrays.asList(4L, 92L, 100L);
DoubleList doubles = DoubleLists.mutable.withAll(
        list.stream().mapToDouble(Long::doubleValue));

Assert.assertEquals(DoubleLists.mutable.with(4.0, 92.0, 100.0), doubles);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the mapToDoubleoperator to convert Long into a Double and then use the toList collector.

```
List<Long> longs = new ArrayList<>();
    longs.add(2316354L);
    longs.add(2456354L);
    longs.add(888354L);

    List<Double> doubles = longs.stream().mapToDouble(e->e).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```